# Why is writeRaster changing my coordinate reference system?

Tags: r, raster, r-raster

I am editing a raster using the `raster` and `rdgal` packages in r.

However, after making the edits and saving the raster using the `writeRaster` function I notice that it has changed the coordinate reference system from [OSGB 1936](https://epsg.io/27700) to [Airy 1830](https://epsg.io/7001-ellipsoid).

Why is this happening and how do I prevent `writeRaster` from doing this?

Comment: What file type are you using?

Comment: I'm using GTiff files

Answer (score 1):

I see this:

```
library(raster)
r <- raster(nrow=10, ncol=10)
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
crs(r) <- "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs"

x <- writeRaster(r, "test.tif")
crs(x)
#CRS arguments:
#+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +towgs84=446.448,-125.157,542.06,0.1502,0.247,0.8421,-20.4894 +units=m +no_defs
```

So the coordinate reference system mostly remains the same (it is still transverse Mercator etc), but the `datum=OSGB36` is dropped.

I do not *why* this happens, but I think it is the same thing (the OSGB36 datum is defined by the airy 1830 ellipsoid).